# Vim opens in REPLACE mode, adding 'set noesckeys' makes arrow keys unusable

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using VIM 8.2 in WSL 1.0 as Ubuntu 16.04, on windows 10 (version 1903) from the Windows Terminal (version 1.0.1401.0).

When I open a file in VIM, it opens in REPLACE mode. I do not want this. I added `set noesckeys` to my .vimrc, and this fixed the issue, but created a new one in arrow keys not working in insert mode (they instead type uppercase letters). I would like for neither of these problems, but currently I can have one or the other.

I have nothing mapped to `<esc>`, I checked with the `:map` command. I'm running in `nocompatible` mode.

How can I fix VIM starting in REPLACE mode without affecting arrow keys in insert mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you mapped your `esc` key? Please show your `vimrc`.

Comment: No, nothing mapped to esc. I though I added that to the post, but I forgot to put it in a code block so it didn't show up

Comment: Enter the following in terminal before starting vim and check if it solves your issue: `export TERM=xterm`.

Comment: @isAif `export TERM=xterm` solved it for me.